# how to convert Sqlalchemy query result to JSON data

Tags: python, json, serialization, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I do:

```
merchant = Merchant.query.all()
data = json.dumps(merchant)
data = json.load(data)
```

This is my queried result:

> company: Rajendra | agent: None | user: zxnGiCqSPl | fullname: CtwrXsGVQZOSEwZtbYTrTkPTDjY | dob : 1989-12-12 | idproof:  | mobile: 8874565109 | email : PuMGDmu@aasaanpay.com | bankName: KOTAK | ifsc: KOTAK5064960 | acNumber: 5696245574 | MDR_Debit: 0.73 | MDR_Credit: 0.96 | MDR_CreditGold : 1.01 | address1: Vindhya C5-222 | address2: OBH | city: Hyderabad | district: Hyderabad | state: statethree | pincode: 677514

Comment: I hope that is dummy data.

Comment: yes this is dummy data for testing purpose. #jamie bull

Comment: that result is not working in my case can you please elaborate it more #rmn

Answer (score 2):

Just put the data into a dictionary and dump the dictionary, or am I missing something:

```
data = {
    'company': merchant.company,
    'agent': merchant.agent,
    'user': merchant.user,
    'fullname': merchant.fullname
    'dob': merchant.dob
    ...
}
jsonified_data = json.dumps(data)
```

And use `json.loads` when loading a JSON string.

```
json.loads(jsonified_data)
```

Comment: I used your concept and created a serialiser function in models and it return dictionary. So it works now. thanks